# How does the compilation of a class work?

Tags: c++

There are many references about compilation/linking process, but I am interested in a more concrete problem: compilation of a class.

The question arises because in general it is necessary to know things before you can use. For example: you can not call the function if it has not previously been declared.

In classes, it is not done in the same way. You can use a member before it appears. What the compiler does? Does the standard says something about a previous stage of compilation?

To be more specific, the following example shows how we can use members defined below.

```
#include <iostream>

class EvenOdd {
public:
   EvenOdd(): value(0) {}

   void assignEven(unsigned v) {
      if (v>0 && v%2==1) {
         std::cout << "Wrong call... is odd" << std::endl;
         assignOdd(v);
      }
      else {
         std::cout << "Right..." << v << " is Even" << std::endl;
         value= v;
      }
   }
   void assignOdd(unsigned v) {
      if (v>0 && v%2==0) {
         std::cout << "Wrong call... is even" << std::endl;
         assignEven(v);
      }
      else {
         std::cout << "Right..." << v << " is Odd" << std::endl;
         value= v;
      }
   }
private:
   unsigned value;
};

int main()
{
  EvenOdd a;
  std::cout << "Do it right..." << std::endl;
  a.assignEven(2);
  std::cout << "doing it wrong..." << std::endl;
  a.assignEven(3);
}
```

We could also add further questions about inline functions, as may be defined after the point of call and the compiler can resolve without problems. I guess the answer is related.

UPDATE: I know the compilation/linkage has several steps. On the other hand, if the compiler accepts calling a function defined bellow is due that the compiler has analized the code in some sense. The question is ¿which kind of previous stage is done before? Moreover... in which part of the standard we find something related to use a member defined bellow?

To know  how the compiler works is very interesting because it has to know details about the function bellow (at least, the header) that seems to correspond actually to compile. Even the data member has to be compiled because you have to relate its type in the context of the function above

It works like the code is reordered but it is not consistent with the example above because both function members call each other. It is like reordering data members and header of functions could be the code that is considered by the compiler.

Comment: The compilation has more than one step.

Comment: @axiac Yeah, but OP seems to know about it. I guess they really ask why it is needed to have a prior declaration for a function, but not for a class member. It does seem inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks @luk32, that's the question!

Comment: C++ does have an odd compilation model.  It inherited single-pass behavior from C.  Beyond its C with Classes heritage, that was pretty necessary way back when 64 KB of memory cost an arm and a leg and disk drives were small and slow.  But yes, it has to use a two-pass model for classes so it can tackle inline functions.  Memory usage is implicitly limited since it only applies to a single class.  Templates are the bigger problem and compilers tend to slow down a great deal when they have to swallow libraries like Boost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard says

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the class-specifier. Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, exception-specifications, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

This in particular means that a member function body may refer to class members declared below it. The standard doesn't care how implementations achieve this. One possible method would be to postpone semantic analysis of member function bodies and other elements specified above until the closing brace of the class is seen.

Answer (score 0):

Functions within classes can access and modify (unless the function is constant) data members without declaring them, because the data members are already declared in the class. In your response to why function do not need declaration in class.

Comment: unfortunately 5 mins late ... (y)